# How do I get the bounds of selected text as a CGRect?

Tags: swift, select, text, bounds, pdfkit

I am trying to include a highlighting function within a pdfViewer. However, in order to add the highlight annotation, I need the bounds for the selected text as a CGRect. Is there any way I can obtain this?

```
let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: bounds, forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an array of selections where each selection corresponds to a single line of the selected text:

```
guard let selections = pdfView.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine()
     else { return }
```

Loop over the selections line by line, then loop over the pages encompassed by each selection, Then create a new highlight annotation with the selection's bounds and add it to the page

```
selections.forEach({ selection in
     selection.pages.forEach({ page in
         let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
         highlight.color = .yellow
         page.addAnnotation(highlight)
     })
 })
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, so how would the user access this functionality? Would the user select the text and then as well as the 'copy', 'paste', 'select all' functions there would be a 'highlight' functionality?

Comment: First section returns selections of the user and then you can get the bounds of the selection and highlight them as you asked. Accessing `UIMenuController` and add some custom `UIMenuItem`s is a different question. I gave you the hint by the way ;)

Comment: Aha thanks so much for the hint :) From this, I was able to add a highlight menu item to a menu controller.